# Getting rolling aggregate number of changes by groups of values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m new to SQL and looking for the best way to do something a little complex, any help would be much appreciated.

I have a CTE with columns similar to this, with the IDs being random sequences:
rule_id, rule_date (unique), goal, condition_group_id, condition_id, condition_property_1, condition_property2, and condition_property3 (which can be NULL).

*Example data:*
[image: Example data]

What I need is a count for every rule_id of all distinct goals that had any change in conditions, condition groups or properties from the previous rule (by date). Since all IDs are changed with every new Rule, I have only the condition properties to compare between rules. A change counts as any one of these:

1. A change in one of the properties for a single condition_id (G2 in the example dataset)
2. A change in the combination of condition_ids that form a condition_group (G1)
3. Adding or removing a condition_group. In the case of removal of all condition groups, the goal will not exist on the rule where it should be counted (G3).

The expected result for this dataset is:

```
Rule_id  | Updated_goal_count
-----------------------------
Rule_id1 | 3
```

I got as far as adding these:
`LAG(Rule_id) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS prev_rule` to compare with for changes
`LEAD(Rule_id) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS next_rule` to get the rules of removed goals
But I can’t figure out how to join the CTE with itself to get all possible condition groups matched efficiently.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @NoaCohenEliash . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  It seems like your definition of "change" requires an ordering, but it is not clear what that is.  I also don't see how the sample data has much to do with the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have the rules ordered by date, sorry I thought that was clearer. Can you tell it's my first time posting a question?....

Comment: @NoaCohenEliash . . . Your conditions seem to be *within* a single rule.  And there is no ordering for that.